# No persistable permission grants found for UID error message when running an espresso test

Tags: android, permissions, android-espresso

I have an app requesting for the access to a folder.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
intent.putExtra("android.provider.extra.SHOW_ADVANCED", true);

mStartChooseFolderForResult.launch(intent);
```

then in OnActivityResult:

```
public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result)
{
    if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK)
    {
        Intent intent = result.getData();
        Uri uri = intent.getData();
        ContentResolver cr = getActivity().getContentResolver();
        int flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
                  | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION;
        cr.takePersistableUriPermission(uri, flags);
        ...
    }
}
```

When I run the app manually, the persistable permission is granted and it works fine even after a reboot.

But when I run the app in a expresso test after a reboot, I get the following error:

```
No persistable permission grants found for UID...
```

If I run the app manually and select the folder of the espresso test and then run the espresso test, then it works fine

Here is my test code (of course, I call Intents.init() before and Intenst.release() after):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(DEFAULT_FOLDER_STRING + "%2F" + testFolder));
Instrumentation.ActivityResult result = new 
    Instrumentation.ActivityResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
intending(hasAction(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE)).respondWith(result);
    
onView(withText("select")).perform(click());
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: First: remove all those flags on both intents. They have no effect and it is only confusing for other readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I fix this error?

My guess is that you will need to eliminate the test.

If all you were doing with the returned `Intent` was looking at it, your mock return `Intent` would be fine. However, you are actually trying to make a system call (`takePersistableUriPermission()`) using the details from that `Intent`. And, the error is pretty straightforward: the OS has no sign of a persistable permission grant for `Uri.parse(DEFAULT_FOLDER_STRING + "%2F" + testFolder)`. Hence, when you call `takePersistableUriPermission()`, the OS is very confused.

If you wish to keep this test, you would need to rewrite your activity/fragment to not call `takePersistableUriPermission()` itself. Instead, that logic would need to be moved elsewhere (e.g., a viewmodel), where your test uses a test double (e.g., a mock or fake), so that your test does not actually call `takePersistableUriPermission()`.

Comment: thanks for your answer.  I guess you're correct. I'll keep my test but before (only once, so not really a problem) I select this folder while running the app manually. Then everything works fine